# When do we say "make a toast to you" and "cheers to you"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Your friend has just got a new job and you and your friend are raising your glasses of beer towards each other.

When do you say "**make a toast to you**" and "**cheers to you!**" in that situation?

**Note**: in the movie ["**Wonder woman 1984**"](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2020/12/26/wonder-woman-1984-transcript/), the woman says "**Well, cheers to us. Wishing us better luck, I guess.**"

Comment: the act is "making a toast", and it it is extremely common in the UK. Every Wedding you "Toast the Bride", Bride and Groom, Bridesmaids etc. The more the merrier unless the bar is on a tight budget ...https://www.weddingideasmag.com/a-z-of-british-wedding-traditions-and-wedding-etiquette/   look under "S" Speeches

Answer (score 1):

As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20a%20toast%20to%20you%2C%20cheers%20to%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20toast%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccheers%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20toast%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccheers%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0) shows, both expressions are extremely rare.

In an informal situation, you would just say "Cheers!".

In formal situations, you would more likely **propose a toast**... that is, you would invite everybody present to raise their glass. This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20a%20toast%2C%20propose%20a%20toast&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20toast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpropose%20a%20toast%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20toast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpropose%20a%20toast%3B%2Cc0) shows that **make a toast** is gaining ground, but most of the actual instances are Mills & Boon (romantic novels aimed at women), where standards of writing are not high.

Comment: I heard "Cheers to us" in the movie "Wonder woman 1984" (https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2020/12/26/wonder-woman-1984-transcript/)

Comment: ... well, I did say "extremely rare", not "incorrect".